# How to turn hexadecimal into decimal using brain?

Tags: hex

Opening the calculator to do such tiny stuff appears annoying to me ,and I strongly believe in ths saying "the more you know,the better!" so here I am asking you how to convert hexadecimal to decimal.

Till that moment I use the following formula:

```
Hex:        Decimal:
12          12+6
22          22+2*6
34          34+3*6
49          49+4*6
99          99+9*6
```

I get confused when I move on at higher numbers like C0 or FB

What is the formula(brain,not functional) that you're using?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you consider that hexadecimal is base 16, its actually quite easy:

Start from the least significant digit and work towards the most significant (right to left) and multiply the digit with increasing powers of 16, then sum the result.

For example:

0x12 = 2 + (1 * 16)
     = 18

0x99 = 9 + (9 * 16)
     = 153

Then, remember that A = 10, B = 11, C = 12, D = 13, E = 14 and F = 15

So,

0xFB = 11 + (15 * 16)
     = 251

Comment: NOTE: This is good only if you need to convert 2 digit hexadecimals. If you need something larger, see the formulas below.

Comment: @Vippy, perhaps the example isn't clear, but  "multiply the digit with increasing powers of 16" does work with more than 2 digits.

Answer (score 18):

That's not the formula.. that's not even somewhat like the formula...

The formula is:

X*16^y where X is the number you want to convert and y is the position for the number (from right to left).

So.. if you want to convert *DA145* to decimal would be..

> (5 * 16^0) + (4 * 16^1) + (1 * 16^2) + (10 * 16^3) + (13 * 16^4)

And you have to remember that the letter are:
A - 10
B - 11
C - 12
D - 13
E - 14
F - 15

Comment: His formula is completely correct (and not merely coincidentally) for the class of numbers on which it operates. It just can't handle more than 2 digits or any of the alpha-digits.

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: Where/how does the formula arise? It seems their formula is pretty random

Answer (score 10):

I pretty much stopped doing this when I found the hex numbers I was working with were 32 bits. Not much fun there.

For smaller numbers, I (eventually) memorized some patterns: 10 = 16, 20 = 32, 40 = 64, 80 = 128 (because 100 = 256, and 80 is one bit less). 200 = 512 I remember because of some machine I used to use whose page size was 512 (no longer remember what machine!). 1000 = 4096 because that's another machine's page size.

also, 64=100, 32=50, B8=200

That's about all. Beyond that, I add.

Comment: Also, 400 = 1024 and 800 = 2048.

Answer (score 7):

For the record, your brain does use a functional method of finding the answer. Here's the function my brain uses to find the value of a hexadecimal number:

1. Divide the hexadecimal number into individual digits.
2. Convert each digit to it's decimal value (so 0-9 stay the same, A is 10, B is 11, etc.)
3. Starting at the rightmost digit, multiply each value by 16^X power, where X is the distance from the rightmost digit (so the rightmost digit is 16^0, or 1, next is 16^1, or 16, next is 16^2, or 256, etc.)
4. Add all the values together.

Answer (score 3):

Memorize the decimal values of 20h, 40h, and so on, up to E0h. (I suppose you already know 100h.)
Then get the decimal values if other numbers by adding or subtracting a number from 1 to 16.

Answer (score 2):

The decimal value will be

```
20h = 0x16^0 + 2x16^1 = 0x1 + 2x16 = 0 + 32 = 32
```

in decimal notation, or `(32)10`.

For `40h` in hexa we will have `64` in decimal, for `EOH`, we will have `224` in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

In determining the decimal value of a specific index in a word, generalized for all bases:

```
b^i*n
```

where b is the base, i is the index in the word, and n is the numeric value at the index. Remember this by remembering that b,i,n = bin = short for binary.

### Examples:

---

for base2 (binary) **1**000, getting the value where the 1 is located:

b = base, ie base2: **b=2**

i = 0-based index within word, ie 1000, 1 is in 3th index, **i=3**

n = number listed in index, ie 1000, 3th index is 1, **n=1**

so, 2^3*1 = 8

---

for base10 (decimal) **9**00, getting the value where the 9 is located:

b=10, i=2, n=9 : 10^2*9 = 100*9 =900

---

for base16 (hexadecimal) 0x0**f**0, getting the value where the f is located:

b=16, i=1, n=15 (0-9,a-f,f=15) : 16^1*15 = 16*15 = 240

---

Note that this can be used to determine the value of each index in a word, then each value can be summed to determine the full word value.

e.g. 1001, from left to right (order doesn't matter in summation):

(2^3*1=8) + (2^2*0=0) + (2^1*0=0) + (2^0*1=1) = 9

Comment: Your equation `b^i*n` is valid ! Do not -1 this post ;)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any of these helpful so here's my way:
Turn it into two sets of binary numbers to represent each letter, then take the whole binary representation and convert to decimal

Example:
AB

A / B

= 1010 / 1011 in binary

= 171 (128 + 0 + 32 + 0 + 8 + 0 + 2 + 1) in decimal

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method that doesn't involve powers of 16 and can be done with pencil and paper:

Start with the leftmost digit. Multiply it by 16 and add to it the second-from-the-left digit.
Then multiply the result by 16 and add to it the third-from-the-left digit. And so on.

For example, converting `0x20A5` to decimal:

```
  2 * 16 +  0 = 32
 32 * 16 + 10 = 522   (remember that A is 10 decimal)
522 * 16 +  5 = 8357
```

And the result of the conversion is 8,357.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread.... but I have a way to convert HEX/DEC/BIN by looking at a chart that is much faster than typing the values into a calculator.  The chart is simply a circle with point values going around starting at 0 and ending at 255.  With that circle you draw 8 lines, equally dividing the circle into 16 "slices of pi(e)". The first line drawn starts at 0 and goes straight down to the 128 position of the circle.  The rest of the lines then count by 16s.  The pie slices are them labeled with 0 - F and for binary 0000 - 1111.  Now using the chart you can visually see the conversion of HEX/DEC/BIN.  For example the DEC number 100 is in the 6 (hex)/0110 Pie slice.  Meaning that the first hex digit for 100 (DEC) would be 6 in hex or 0110 in BIN.  Subtracting 100 from 96 equal 4, which is the second HEX digit.  In the pie 4 = 0100 therefore 100(dec) = 64(hex) = 01100100(bin).  Practice using the attached graphic, and you will see that, with this chart, you can now convert faster this way than with a calculator.
[image: HEX/DEC/BIN converstion Chart]