# HEX Code into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fill, khan-academy

How do I put a HEX code into Khan Academy's JavaScript? I would like to make it a fill color, but I can not find the right command. I have tried many things that people have also tried but none seem to work on Khan Academy. Please help.

Comment: hex Values in JS are prepended with `0x` and in CSS it's `#` so JS: `var red = 0xFF0000;` CSS: `background-color: #F00;`

Comment: What does JS have to do with colors? And how is that specific to Khan Academy? Please post the code that you have.

Comment: I have JavaScript.

Comment: It's just that in Khan Academy, a lot of the codes for the JavaScript don't work

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert from hexadecimal to decimal. With the color functions on KA, you will have three decimal numbers seperated by commas representing the hex codes. For example:

`0xFFFFFF`
would be:
`color(255,255,255);`

The color commands in KA:

````
background(r, g, b)
Set the background color

fill(r, g, b)
Set the fill color for shapes

noFill()
Turn off fill for shapes

stroke(r, g, b)
Set the outline color for shapes

strokeWeight(thickness)
Change the thickness of lines and outlines

noStroke()
Turn off outlines for shapes

color(r, g, b)
Store a color in a variable

blendColor(c1, c2, MODE)
Blend two colors together

lerpColor(c1, c2, amount)
Find color between 2 colors```
````

Comment: To convert from Hex to Decimal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910309/how-to-turn-hexadecimal-into-decimal-using-brain