# How to convert hex code to decimal code or vice versa

Tags: hex, decimal, converters

How can I know what these bunch of hex code means?

02 00 A0 E3 1E FF 2F E1

Any convertor of these codes to decimal code like 1,2,3 etc or vice versa like deciaml code to this type of hex code?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn hexadecimal into decimal using brain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910309/how-to-turn-hexadecimal-into-decimal-using-brain)

Comment: Entering "hex to decimal converter" in any internet search engine reveals tons of converters. Also, any scientific calculator, incl. the ones on Mac and Windows, can do this kind of calculation.

Answer (score 2):

This is my first response in stack overflow. So here goes...

What Hex Code (a.k.a. hexadecimal) represents purely depends on its context, or what does it mean to the program or machine.  It could be a string, machine code (assembly language), flags, pointers to memory, data, part of an image or whatever.  And this is dependent on the processor where this code is located also.

Each 2-digit hex code is a byte and represents decimal number (0-255 or 00-FF), half of a byte or 1 digit hex code is called a nibble.

Converting Hex Code to decimal is trivial.  Convert from decimal to hex, not as trivial.

There are many calculators that have this functionality built in.
0-9 => 0 – 9, A=10, B=11, C=12, D=13, E=14, F=15.

Now, if you want to convert a 2 digit number like 12 hex (i.e. 0x12 or 12h ).  Here is the formula.

(16 x 1) + (1 x 2) = 18 (decimal)

A four-digit hexadecimal 4A3E =>

(4096 x 4) + (256 x 10) + (16 x 3) + (1 x 14) = 19006 (decimal)

An integer in C# is 4 bytes, so your example hex code could also represent 2 integers in C#. Or it could be simply 1 number in C# called a “long” which is 8 bytes and could represent a number between:

0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 unsigned long OR
-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 signed long

Also something to note hex code also represent characters called ASCII (pronounced a·skee)  This is an internal mapping within the microprocessor and could be different. 00 is not mapped so it typically means the end of the string.

Comment: Great explanation, Ricky!  Keep doing it!

Answer (score 0):

Hex codes like that could represent a binary number.  You could paste "0200A0E31EFF2FE1" into a converter like [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-binary.html) to find out that the decimal representation of that number is "144292085413916641", for example.

But, from the way that your hex codes are grouped, it appears that you're looking at binary data, rather than a single integer that's represented in hexadecimal.  When hex codes are grouped in pairs, each group of two characters represents one byte.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Written_representation